# some executables will not execute

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

My computer stopped working. I replaced the motherboard and processor (had an Intel i3, got an AMD Ryzen) and installed Ubuntu 18.04.03 on the disk where I had had the system before. The system boots and I can use quite a few programs. But, for example, I downloaded google-chrome and installed it, but the executable will not execute.

When I installed google chrome, the executable ended up in /opt/google/chrome. Here is the 'ls -l'

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      1873 oct  9 04:59 google-chrome
```

When I try to run it as root, I get

```
root@garey-machine:/opt/google/chrome# ./google-chrome
-su: ./google-chrome: Permission denied
```

Is this a problem with the executables being Intel code? Is it a problem with some security system I am not aware of? Any help?

Comment: Is this a problem with the executables being Intel code? --> No, Intel and AMD are binary compatible.

Comment: You can't run browsers as root without `no-sandbox`.